# Inserting references into xtable in Rmd document

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

I'm embedding an xtable-formatted table into a paper where I need to include citations. For example, check out [this table](http://mbio.asm.org/content/7/4/e01018-16/T1.expansion.html). In the second row it has "Baxter (23)" where the 23 is the reference number. When we made that table, we hard coded the reference number (code [here](https://github.com/SchlossLab/Sze_Obesity_mBio_2016/blob/master/results/tables/table_1.Rmd)). Is there a direct way to do this within `knitr` if we put the table inside the manuscript Rmd file? When I do this and instead of the `23` put`" [@SchlossXXXX]"` it renders as `[@SchlossXXXX]`.

Comment: Show a MWE of what you have tried.